# Weird issue with "this" losing its value in a validation function in aspect.around. Or, aspect.around is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, dojo

**Note: please keep in mind that this is not a generic question on the use of `this` on javascript. This is about aspect.around malfunctioning (it's meant to set the scope for the call, and it doesn't). The question is: why is aspect.around malfunctioning? this question needs you to read carefully how to reproduce and do so with the fiddle provided!**

I had to shred my app to pieces in order to make the problem fit in a fiddle.
So here it is:

http://jsfiddle.net/mercmobily/THtsv/1/

It's a simple form, with validation:

- Type something in the textbox: the validation method of the widget will be called.
- Then press the submit button: validation will fail, and aspect.around will be called to wrap something around the validation method.
- At *that* point, try to type anything in the textbox again:  It will come back with an error, as the validator will fail because of "this" being set to "window" instead of the widget.

So, once the aspect is added, the validator *stops* working. Basically, the value of "this" gets lost. Now:

- aspect.around() is meant to run the new validator in the right scope (obviously) and it's *failing* to do so
- I can "fix" this problem by changing the call to the validator into this: `return originalValidator.call(this, value);` However, it doesn't answer the question "Why is 'this' lost?"
- If you backtrace the code, you will see that aspect.around() is doing what it normally does... but it must be doing *something* wrong

So, the question: why is dojo.around() malfunctioning, not setting `this` to the passed object's scope?

Merc.

Comment: What's assigned to `this` in your function? Check that using `console.log`

Comment: Did you have a look at the fiddle? It calls aspect.around which it's meant to set the scope of the passed method. It normally does, but not in this case...

Comment: I'm asking what it's set to, not what it's supposed to be set to...

Comment: Sorry! It's the `window` object. It's clear by the error you get from the fiddle...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not very easy to follow what exactly you're asking.  From your jsFiddle, I see this comment so I'll attempt to answer the question you pose here:

```
  // QUESTION: FIND OUT WHY WE NEED THIS "call"
  return originalValidator(value);
  // return originalValidator.call(this, value);
```

The answer to why you need the `.call` here in order to preserve the value of `this` is as I described below in the generic description of how `this` works when making a function call.

When you make an ordinary function call as in this statement:

```
  return originalValidator(value);
```

The value of `this` is set back to `window`.  That's how javascript works.  If you want to preserve the current value of `this` in that function, you have to specify that you want a particular value of `this` set using `.call()` or `.apply()` or an `obj.method()` call.  The value of `this` in an ordinary function call is NOT bound to the function.  It's set by the caller and can be anything the caller wants.  If you don't specify it, then javascript sets `this` to `window` and that is exactly what is happening in your code.

---

Here's the generic description of how the value of `this` is set and this generic description applies in your specific case.

The simple rule is that the value of `this` is reset on every single function call in javascript.  If it's just a plain function call, then `this` is set to the global object (which is `window` in the browser environment).  So any simple function call will always set `this` to `window`.

If you make a method call like `obj.method()`, then `this` will be set to point to the `obj` while in the `method()`.

If you use `func.apply(a, b)` or `func.call(a, b)` then you can explicitly control what `this` is set to via the value of the first argument to `.apply()` or `.call()`.  See this MDN doc [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) for more info on `.call()` and `.apply()`.

Comment: I am aware of all this. Dojo is indeed meant to set the scope when doing aspect.around()asthere wouldn't be any point in doing it any other way. If you backtrace the code, you will see exactly what I mean: the scope IS indeed set, and it's set to the right widget! (Thanks for having a look!)

Comment: @Merc - OK, I've looked at your specific jsFiddle and seen the place where you ask a question about the call to `originalValidator()` and I've attempted to address that specific issue.

Comment: I clarified the question further... sorry about it not being 100% clear beforehand. The question in a few words is "Why is dojo.aspect malfunctioning?" It's meant to set this, it normally does... but not in this case!

Comment: @Merc - the code that appears to be malfunctioning is your own code, not `dojo.aspect` code.   Though I don't know `dojo.aspect` in any detail, my guess would be that you aren't using it properly.

Comment: My own code just calls `aspect.around()`. So, *that* is malfunctioning. Caused by my code? I don't know. I am still trying to find out (as we speak, actually).

Comment: @Merc - isn't the callback function you provided to `aspect.around()` your code?  That's the code that has the fault.  If you look at the `aspect.around()` example on [this page](http://davidwalsh.name/dojo-aspect), it calls the original method with `.apply()` just like you discovered your code needs in order to function properly (`.call()` and `.apply()` do similar things).

Comment: Oh my... so aspect.around does NOT set the scope, like I had assumed/thought by reading the code! Ouch, triple ouch, answer accepted with many humble thanks!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15527/discussion-between-merc-and-jfriend00)

Answer (score 0):

`this` is the current context. By default it's the global object (or `null` in strict mode), when calling a function on an object (`foo.bar()`) it's set to that object. When using `.call()` or `.apply()` to call a function it's set to whatever first argument was passed to that function.

This means that you cannot assume that `this` is still the same when you go into another function - even if you define that function in a context where `this` is what you want.

The most common approach is adding `var self = this;` and then using `self` instead of `this` in the inner function - since `self` is a normal variable it will be in the function's closure and not be affected by `this` being bound to something else in the function.

Comment: I am aware of all this. Dojo is indeed meant to set the scope when doing `aspect.around()` as there wouldn't be any point in doing it any other way. If you backtrace the code, you will see exactly what I mean: the scope IS indeed set, and it's set to the right widget! (Thanks for having a look!)